# Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer.Reset()'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, rdlc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6aum.jpg)

Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer.Reset()'.

After using this Reset method on my asp RV control, now the page issues this error:
I tried downloading ReportViewer.exe 2005 Redistr. from the MS site and installed at the server but still get same error.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got Solution for this Problem.
This Error Occurs because of the .dll difference in Production and node systems.
Once i Changed the dll same in both systems then its working fine..
Thanks!!!